# Rails after_save error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, after-save

Is this the correct way of using after_save callback ?

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
after_save :remove_restrictions
 private
    def remove_restrictions

      logger.debug("in after save")
    end

end
```

This code throws the error as

```
undefined method `after_save' for CouponsController:Class
```

What is the correct way of using after_save ?

Comment: Put your after save in your Model

Comment: @rubyist - if you want to put this as an answer, I'll delete mine.  I think we answered around the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

app/models/coupon.rb

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  # after_save goes to your model
  after_save :remove_restrictions

  private

  def remove_restrictions
    logger.debug("in after save")
  end
end
```

app/controllers/coupon_controller.rb

```
class CouponController < ApplicationController
  # after_filters goes to your controller
  after_filter :remove_restrictions

  private

  def remove_restrictions
    logger.debug("in after filters")
  end
end
```

Comment: oops my bad ! Got it now, Thx

Comment: btw, jus curious can I query for records in the after_save callback ?

Comment: I mean can i write controller code in the model callback , like "@list=Coupons.all"

Comment: yes you can write...but the purpose of callbacks are different............for more info check here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html